# Sshpass in a loop

Tags: linux, ssh

Why when using `sshpass` in a loop the first `sshpass` executes commands, while the next does not?

```
for element in "${a[@]}"
 do {
     echo "$element"
     sshpass -p "omg" ssh root@$element 'ls' 
    }
done
```

Comment: Can we have some context, like for instance what `a` is?

Comment: a is an array with containing ip's of VM's

Comment: fixed it use:      echo "$element";
   export SSHPASS='omg' ;sshpass -e  ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$element  'ls' 
unset SSHPASS

Comment: Do not add additional information in the comment section. Better edit your question with the new information.

Comment: @Goking make an answer to this question and mark it as the solution. Remove the fixed code sample from the question and place it in the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix:

```
for element in "${a[@]}" do
   echo "$element"
   export SSHPASS='omg'
   sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$element 'ls'
   unset SSHPASS
done
```

Comment: Note: the question is "why?" and the answer explains nothing. It *may or may not* be an example of [voodoo programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voodoo_programming), but without explanation it will be useful mostly to voodoo programmers.

Comment: I guess it has to do something with the prompt : add this host? and you have to type yes . Besides that it works perfectly fine without the loop, even the host is not added in a script it assumes yes.